# Disable a Radio button based on label text portion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have some radio buttons with different values (so I cannot use values like on other situations). Is it possible to disable the click event for the radio button based on a certain text available in the label?

E.g. if I have following four items as radio buttons and various products have various sizes and colors but some items will have similar text like `(0)` or `(20)` etc. ( it is the number of available items)

**Item 1**

1. Red Small (20)
2. Red Large (20)
3. Red EXtra Large (0)
4. Red EXtra EXtra Large (0)

**Item 2**

1. Pink Small (20)
2. Pink Large (20)
3. Pink Slimfit (0)

So like wise many products available but only similar thing will be the text `(0)`.

How to disable click event if radio button has text `(0)` in the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `disabled` property based on whether the number is `0` or not. For example if you had the following markup:

```
<label>A (0)<input type="radio" /></label>
<label>B (32)<input type="radio" /></label>
<label>C (0)<input type="radio" /></label>
<label>D (5)<input type="radio" /></label>
```

You could do something like this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').prop('disabled', function() {
   return $(this).parent().text().match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1] == 0; 
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mDuv/8/)

Comment: Wow this is perfect.. It works fine with standard radio buttons..,  i made some changes to radio buttons using this http://viralpatel.net/blogs/css-radio-button-checkbox-background/   article ( up to 2nd point css) .. hope you could help me to get this working with my requirement..   I tried it as follows ; $('input[type=radio] + label').prop('disabled', function() {
   return $(this).parent().text().match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1] == 0; 
});       but didn`t work...

Comment: @JohnAnderson You need to show your markup, can you edit your question to include it?

Comment: it is a system based on opencart.. shall i send you a demo link of the site to you..

Comment: by the way any possibility to add a different bg color to once with 0 so that user knows it is disabled..(or even change of text colors in label would do )

Answer (score 4):

You can disable a radio button dynamically using the following code.

```
if(condition satisfies)
{
   $(this).attr('disabled',true);
}
```

Comment: hello.. can you tell me how i have to make this condition.. Basically if the label ( text) of the radio option has (0)   then i want to hide it... Hope you could help me here.. thankx